# IFSAR data for New Mexico areas

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

I am looking for an [IFSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometric_synthetic_aperture_radar) 5m data between Las Cruces, New Mexico and Carlsbad, New Mexico and from Roswell, NM to the south of New Mexico and Texas border.

I am looking for a free data.